# IE9 GetPropertyByName failing

Tags: javascript, c++, com, internet-explorer-9, atl

Hi We are using IE9 in non-compatibility mode.

We are doing something like this to read JS variable values from browser side:

```
ComPtr<IDispatch> disp;
m_spBrowser->get_Document(&disp);

CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument2> htmlDoc = disp;
if( !htmlDoc ) return ZString();

CComPtr<IHTMLWindow2> spWindow;
htmlDoc->get_parentWindow(&spWindow);

CComVariant varRes;
CComDispatchDriver dispWindow = spWindow;
if( dispWindow ) {
    HRESULT hr = dispWindow.GetPropertyByName(L"returnValue", &varRes);
    if( SUCCEEDED(hr) && SUCCEEDED(varRes.ChangeType(VT_BSTR)) ) 
        return CString(varRes.bstrVal);
}
return CString();
```

We are using old version of ATL.

Now this routine always fails when run in IE9 non-compatibility mode. "returnValue" is Null and we get 0 value for GetLastError.

Any ideas? Is it a known issue and if so any fixes/workarounds?

Comment: We expect to get window.top.returnValue and access JS variables from C++ side. We are using MSVC 6 ATL if it helps.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342200/how-do-i-call-eval-in-ie-from-c/18349546#18349546) for an example of `IDispatchEx::GetDispID` on `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is querying property named `returnValue` from the COM object, for which you have `IHTMLWindow2` interface pointer. This does not have to work out because you assume the property exists, and documentation says otherwise:

[returnValue property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752698%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Remarks
>
> This property applies **only** to windows created by using the
>   `IHTMLWindow2::showModalDialog` method.

More to that, the property belongs to `IHTMLDialog` interface, so you could perhaps access it directly without relying on `CComDispatchDriver`'s abilities to find path to it via `IDispatch`/`IDispatchEx`named property access.

Comment: We set the JS object value as window.top.returnValue=<some value>. According to your logic, the code would have failed for all browsers..not only IE9. Also why would I get the error value as 0(action completed successfully)?

Comment: `1` my logic is that you might be getting the property more accurately instead of expecting to be found via name lookup `2` `GetLastError` is not expected to get you any error code here, instead you need to step into the function and check things there. `hr` might have a related error code.

Comment: Any idea how I can get the IHTMLDialog object in the above code/function? I am creating the modal dialog from else where and I just need to read the returnValue property from the above funtion. Also can it be a limitation of ATL 3.0 becasue all other browser/platforms work fine..

Comment: So I tried this but does not work(gives error at QueryInterface)  ComPtr<IHTMLWindow2> spWindow;
    
               htmlDoc->get_parentWindow(&spWindow);
           hr = spWindow->get_external(&disp);
           CComQIPtr<IHTMLDialog> spDlg;
           hr = disp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDialog , (void **) &spDlg);