# How do I call eval() in IE from C++?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com

With the advent of IE11, [`IHTMLWindow2::execScript()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is deprecated. The recommended approach is to [use `eval()` instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#legacyAPIs). I'm automating IE via its C++ COM interfaces, and I have been unable to find how to accomplish this. Can someone point me to the example I've obviously missed in my searching? If it's not possible to execute code via `eval`, what's the appropriate way to inject JavaScript code into a running instance of Internet Explorer now that `execScript` is no longer available?

**EDIT:** Any solution that will work for the project I'm working on must work out-of-process. I am not using a Browser Helper Object (BHO), or any type of IE plugin. Thus, any solution that involves an interface that cannot be properly marshaled cross-process won't work for me.

Comment: My guess is that you'd do it like you would in JavaScript, by adding a new script element to the DOM of the page, but I'm checking with the IE dev team...

Comment: @JimEvans, I don't have IE11 installed to try, but the following works for IE10 using `eval`: `CComDispatchDriver window = m_window; /* of IHTMLWindow2 */ 
window.Invoke1(L"eval", &CComVariant(L"alert(true)"));`

Answer (score 14):

I have now verified the `eval` approach works consistently with IE9, IE10 and IE11 (error checks skipped for breavity):

```
CComVariant result;
CComDispatchDriver disp = m_htmlWindow; // of IHTMLWindow2
disp.Invoke1(L"eval", &CComVariant(L"confirm('See this?')"), &result);
result.ChangeType(VT_BSTR);
MessageBoxW(V_BSTR(&result));
```

Feels even better than `execScript`, because it actually returns the `result`.
It works also in C# with WinForms' `WebBrowser`:

```
var result = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { "confirm('see this?')" });
MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

That said, `execScript` still works for IE11 Preview:

```
CComVariant result;
m_htmlWindow->execScript(CComBSTR(L"confirm('See this too?')"), CComBSTR(L"JavaScript"), &result);
result.ChangeType(VT_BSTR);
MessageBoxW(V_BSTR(&result));
```

And it still discards the `result`, as it always did.

A bit off-topic, but you don't have to stick with `eval` for this. This approach allows to execute any named method available inside the namespace of the JavaScript `window` object of the loaded page (via [IDispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface). You may call your own function and pass a live COM object into it, rather than a string parameter, e.g.:

```
// JavaScript
function AlertUser(user)
{
  alert(user.name);
  return user.age;
}

// C++
CComDispatchDriver disp = m_htmlWindow; // of IHTMLWindow2
disp.Invoke1(L"AlertUser", &CComVariant(userObject), &result);
```

I'd prefer the above direct call to `eval` where possible.

**[EDITED]**

It takes some tweaks to make this approach work for out-of-process calls. As @JimEvans pointed out in the comments, `Invoke` was returning error 0x80020006 ("Unknown name"). However, a [test HTA app](http://pastebin.com/cLR6FeJV) worked just fine, what made me think to try [IDispatchEx::GetDispId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwazwk2k%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) for name resolution. That indeed worked (error checks skipped):

```
CComDispatchDriver dispWindow;
htmlWindow->QueryInterface(&dispWindow);

CComPtr<IDispatchEx> dispexWindow;
htmlWindow->QueryInterface(&dispexWindow);

DISPID dispidEval = -1;
dispexWindow->GetDispID(CComBSTR("eval"), fdexNameCaseSensitive, &dispidEval);
dispWindow.Invoke1(dispidEval, &CComVariant("function DoAlert(text) { alert(text); }")); // inject

DISPID dispidDoAlert = -1;
dispexWindow->GetDispID(CComBSTR("DoAlert"), fdexNameCaseSensitive, &dispidDoAlert) );
dispWindow.Invoke1(dispidDoAlert, &CComVariant("Hello, World!")); // call
```

The full C++ test app is here: http://pastebin.com/ccZr0cG2

**[UPDATE]**

This update creates `__execScript` method on a `window` object of a child `iframe`, out-of-proc. The code to be injected was optimized to return the target `window` object for later use (no need to make a series of out-of-proc calls to obtain the `iframe` object, it's done in the context of the main window):

```
CComBSTR __execScriptCode(L"(window.__execScript = function(exp) { return eval(exp); }, window.self)");
```

Below is the code for C++ console app ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cLR6FeJV)), some error checks skipped for breavity. There's also a corresponding [prototype in .HTA](http://pastebin.com/iM5829MM), which is more readable.

```
//
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342200/how-do-i-call-eval-in-ie-from-c/18349546//
//

#include <tchar.h>
#include <ExDisp.h>
#include <mshtml.h>
#include <dispex.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcomcli.h>

#define _S(a) \
    { HRESULT hr = (a); if (FAILED(hr)) return hr; } 

#define disp_cast(disp) \
    ((CComDispatchDriver&)(void(static_cast<IDispatch*>(disp)), reinterpret_cast<CComDispatchDriver&>(disp)))

struct ComInit {
    ComInit() { ::CoInitialize(NULL); }
    ~ComInit() { CoUninitialize(); }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ComInit comInit;

    CComPtr<IWebBrowser2> ie;
    _S( ie.CoCreateInstance(L"InternetExplorer.Application", NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER) );
    _S( ie->put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE) );
    CComVariant ve;
    _S( ie->Navigate2(&CComVariant(L"http://jsfiddle.net/"), &ve, &ve, &ve, &ve) );

    // wait for page to finish loading
    for (;;)
    {
        Sleep(250);
        READYSTATE rs = READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED;
        ie->get_ReadyState(&rs);
        if ( rs == READYSTATE_COMPLETE )
            break;
    }

    // inject __execScript into the main window

    CComPtr<IDispatch> dispDoc;
    _S( ie->get_Document(&dispDoc) );
    CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> htmlDoc;
    _S( dispDoc->QueryInterface(&htmlDoc) );
    CComPtr<IHTMLWindow2> htmlWindow;
    _S( htmlDoc->get_parentWindow(&htmlWindow) );
    CComPtr<IDispatchEx> dispexWindow;
    _S( htmlWindow->QueryInterface(&dispexWindow) );

    CComBSTR __execScript("__execScript");
    CComBSTR __execScriptCode(L"(window.__execScript = function(exp) { return eval(exp); }, window.self)");

    DISPID dispid = -1;
    _S( dispexWindow->GetDispID(CComBSTR("eval"), fdexNameCaseSensitive, &dispid) );
    _S( disp_cast(dispexWindow).Invoke1(dispid, &CComVariant(__execScriptCode)) ); 

    // inject __execScript into the child frame

    WCHAR szCode[1024];
    wsprintfW(szCode, L"document.all.tags(\"iframe\")[0].contentWindow.eval(\"%ls\")", __execScriptCode.m_str);

    dispid = -1;
    _S( dispexWindow->GetDispID(__execScript, fdexNameCaseSensitive, &dispid) );
    CComVariant vIframe;
    _S( disp_cast(dispexWindow).Invoke1(dispid, &CComVariant(szCode), &vIframe) ); // inject __execScript and return the iframe's window object
    _S( vIframe.ChangeType(VT_DISPATCH) );

    CComPtr<IDispatchEx> dispexIframe;
    _S( V_DISPATCH(&vIframe)->QueryInterface(&dispexIframe) );

    dispid = -1;
    _S( dispexIframe->GetDispID(__execScript, fdexNameCaseSensitive, &dispid) );
    _S( disp_cast(dispexIframe).Invoke1(dispid, &CComVariant("alert(document.URL)")) ); // call the code inside child iframe

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right about calling any named function. That's exactly the approach my project takes. However, it's injecting that function _into_ the page where we are currently using `execScript`, and which needs to be replaced. N.B., we don't have any control whatsoever what pages our library may be used against, so we can't modify the source of the page to directly create the global function.

Comment: In this case you could use `eval` first to inject a new global function, the call it. It does work: `disp.Invoke1(L"eval", &CComVariant(L"function GlobalTest() { alert(true); }"));`

Comment: Regarding your out-of-process concern, I haven't tried it out-of-proc, but I'm confident it will work as is. It's done via `IDispatch` which gets marshaled automatically. No extra plumbing needed.

Comment: When I try using your code, or try using `GetIDsOfNames` on the IDispatch for `eval`, I receive an HRESULT of 0x80020006 ("Unknown name"), which leads me to believe that there's an in-process/out-of-process check in place.

Comment: Interesting. I've briefly tried automating IE from an .HTA app and `eval` still works out-of-proc: http://pastebin.com/cLR6FeJV. I'll try the same as a C++ app tomorrow.

Comment: You were right, it did not work as is **for out-of-proc calls**. A solution was to use [IDispatchEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sky96ah7(v=vs.94).aspx) for name resolution. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Your solution is fine as far as it goes, but it doesn't completely meet my needs. Attempting to execute script in the context of a frame/iframe won't work. `IDispatchEx::GetDispID` returns the same "Unknown name" HRESULT for the IHTMLWindow2 object associated with the frame.

Comment: Could you elaborate how you obtain the frame's window IHTMLWindow2 object out-of-proc? I've tried `browser.Document.all.tags("iframe")[0].contentWindow` and I'm getting *Permission denied* on the last step - `contentWindow` (IE10).

Comment: That should work, and does in my environment, as long as you don't cross any Protected Mode boundaries along the way. The full code of my project is available [on GitHub](http://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium), in particular, in the IEDriverServer project therein. The `DocumentHost` class contains the code used to change frame focus.

Comment: It indeed works, the problem was that I tested it against a site with cross-domain frames. I just tried it against jsfiddle.net and `eval` still works: `ie.Document.all.tags("iframe")[0].contentWindow.eval("alert(true)")`, both HTA and C++. Perhaps, the frame's document must be fully navigated first for that to work. I'll be sure to check how it's done in IEDriverServer, just need a bit more of spare time.

Comment: Well, right now, I'm using `execScript`, so this won't be an exact match. However, all script execution is localized to a single class, and I'd be happy to walk you through it at your convenience.

Comment: Here's another idea, an HTA prototype injecting into a child frame from the context of the main window: http://pastebin.com/1xK049DH. Here `eval` is called out-of-proc only for the main window.

Comment: Based upon the fact that `eval` can actually return a result, here's an [improved version](http://pastebin.com/iM5829MM) of the above, which does: `var iframe = ie.Document.parentWindow.__execScript('document.all.tags("iframe")[0].contentWindow');`. I'm going to verify this with C++.

Comment: Thought I'd link here a [C# version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18546866/1768303) of `IDispatchEx` invoker , for relevancy.

Comment: `GetDispID` with "eval" doesn't work in IE8. Using "Function" (the function constructor) works though.

Comment: @Robw, I haven't tried it under IE8, but generally for `eval` to work, but there has to be at least one `<script>` element on the page, even an empty one. It can be easily injected: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19002650/1768303

Comment: I have tried to use this approach and modified Selenium IEDriverServer to use "eval" in hope it will fix the access denied issues I see. Unfortunately, it did not. :(

Comment: @wilx i'm a little late, but you can keep using execScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31605264/1160796

Comment: @basher isn't it ironic how we're stuck with supporting IE11 forever?

Comment: @noseratio I love me some automation with shDocVw.InternetExplorer. As painful as IE11 is, I'm afraid of what would happen if it turned into Edge. Things would start randomly breaking because someone installed X windows update. At least IE11 isn't changing. Do they even offer an edge version? btw - I learned the `.Navigate(); ... await xxx.Task; dostuff` from some of your code samples elsewhere on SO a while ago. I was using like `function x_documentcomplete { dostuff..` instead of the delegate with `await`. Holy hell you cleaned up my code. Way more readable now that it's serial. Thank you

Comment: @basher, yeah they now have [WebDriver for Edge](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/06/14/webdriver-w3c-recommendation-feature-on-demand/) which they promise to keep updating along side with Edge. But there is another emerging trend: ElectronJS. That allows to abandon the IE legacy and wrap the whole web app with a Desktop envelop so it will run not only on Win7 but also on Mac an Linux, using the cutting-edge web standards (including `async/await` that you liked). [I'm jumping on that wagon, too](https://github.com/noseratio/electron-quick-start) ;-)

Comment: @noseratio very nice, i'll have to check it out. Thanks!